# Object not up to date when using mongoose .save()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For some reason, the function .save() isn't saving my documents on MongoDB. All seem right and the first two registers work and update successfully, but my third register 'specialBanner' doesn't work.

When I console log service it doesn't show as part of the special object, although when I console special.specialBanner it is there.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?
Thanks for your help :)

```
const updateSpecial = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { title, description, specialBanner } = req.body;

  let special;

  try {
    special = await Special.findById(specialId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not update special.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  if (title) {
    special.title = title;
  }

  if (description) {
    special.description = description;
  }

  if (specialBanner) {
    special.specialBanner = specialBanner;
  }

  try {
  //Here if I check 'special I get all the right inputs, but the 'specialBanner'. 
    special = await special.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not update special.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(200).json({ special: special.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};
```

Comment: I sorted it out. It happened I made some changes and didn’t update my models to reflect them. 

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mongoose and, `Special` is a collection.

Replace the line

```
special = await Special.findById(specialId)
```

with

```
special = await Special.findById(specialId).exec()
```